# How to get adresesses/values of ranges nested in a collection

Tags: vba, excel

I have a collection of ranges as following:

```
Dim all_pivots_amounts As New Collection

all_pivots_amounts.Add (corporate_amounts)
all_pivots_amounts.Add (wealth_amounts)
all_pivots_amounts.Add (institutional_amounts)
all_pivots_amounts.Add (premium_amounts)
all_pivots_amounts.Add (one_bank_one_bank_amounts)
all_pivots_amounts.Add (one_bank_entrepreneurs_amounts)

Debug.Print corporate_amounts.Address
Debug.Print all_pivots_amounts(1).Address ' this line gives object required 
    error
```

I don't know why the second `Debug.print` line gives "Object required error" (I have also tried `.Items` method). I need to use something similar because I want to print the addresses in a loop instead of specifically calling each range.

Full code:

```
Sub BA_view_new()

Application.EnableEvents = False

Call SetWorkbooks
Call update_pivot_data_sources

Dim corporate_table As PivotTable
Dim wealth_table As PivotTable
Dim institutional_table As PivotTable
Dim premium_table As PivotTable
Dim one_bank_one_bank_table As PivotTable
Dim one_bank_entrepreneurs As PivotTable

Dim corporate_amounts As Range
Dim wealth_amounts As Range
Dim institutional_amounts As Range
Dim premium_amounts As Range
Dim one_bank_one_bank_amounts As Range
Dim one_bank_entrepreneurs_amounts As Range


'get pivots
Set corporate_table = BA_view_pivots_sheet.PivotTables("Corporate & Investment Banking")
Set wealth_table = BA_view_pivots_sheet.PivotTables("Wealth Management & Private Clients")
Set institutional_table = BA_view_pivots_sheet.PivotTables("Institutional Clients")
Set premium_table = BA_view_pivots_sheet.PivotTables("Premium Clients CH")
Set one_bank_one_bank_table = BA_view_pivots_sheet.PivotTables("One Bank Switzerland->One Bank Switzerland")
Set one_bank_entrepreneurs = BA_view_pivots_sheet.PivotTables("One Bank Switzerland->Bank For Entrepreneurs")

'get pivots' amounts
Set corporate_amounts = corporate_table.DataBodyRange
Set wealth_amounts = wealth_table.DataBodyRange
Set institutional_amounts = institutional_table.DataBodyRange
Set premium_amounts = premium_table.DataBodyRange
Set one_bank_one_bank_amounts = one_bank_one_bank_table.DataBodyRange
Set one_bank_entrepreneurs_amounts = one_bank_entrepreneurs.DataBodyRange

'create collection
Dim all_pivots_amounts As New Collection

all_pivots_amounts.Add (corporate_amounts)
all_pivots_amounts.Add (wealth_amounts)
all_pivots_amounts.Add (institutional_amounts)
all_pivots_amounts.Add (premium_amounts)
all_pivots_amounts.Add (one_bank_one_bank_amounts)
all_pivots_amounts.Add (one_bank_entrepreneurs_amounts)

Debug.Print corporate_amounts.Address
Debug.Print all_pivots_amounts(1).Address ' this line gives object required 
error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to qualify the ranges you add as ranges or objects. Otherwise, VBA considers them variants. And the `Variants` do not have `.Address` property. Thus, an object is required:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim all_pivots_amounts As New Collection
    Dim someRange As Range
    Dim someOtherRange As Range

    Set someRange = Range("A1:A10")
    Set someOtherRange = Range("A66")

    all_pivots_amounts.Add someRange
    all_pivots_amounts.Add someOtherRange

    Debug.Print all_pivots_amounts(1).Address
    Debug.Print all_pivots_amounts.Item(1).Address
    Debug.Print all_pivots_amounts(2).Address
    Debug.Print all_pivots_amounts.Item(2).Address

End Sub
```

Once you do this you can use both `.Item(index)` and `(1)`, as in the example.

---

The range variables are passed without parenthesis. If you use parenthesis, VBA is forced to get the arguments `ByVal`. And to get a `Range()` ByVal means, that VBA is adding its value to the collection, thus it is no more object, but `Variant`. This is a simple example of what you see in the Watch Window if you pass ranges like this:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim newColl As New Collection
    Dim someRange As Range: Set someRange = Range("A1")
    Dim someOtherRange As Range: Set someOtherRange = Range("A66")

    Range("A1") = 55
    newColl.Add (someRange)
    newColl.Add someOtherRange

End Sub
```

`Item1` is `Double` and `Item2` is `Object/Range`:

[image]

---

Here are two references about this:

- [Byref byVal from Cpearson](http://cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx)
- [Refer byVal, when parameter is byRef](https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-how-to-refer-a-function-byval-when-the-parameter-is-explicitly-referred-byref/) (Disclaimer: Article from my blog)

Comment: But they are qualified, please see my question updated with full code.

Comment: @barciewicz - then the problem is in the parenthesis, when you pass `all_pivot_amounts.Add`. The parenthesis force argument `byVal`, and the only way to get `ByVal` or a range is to get its value. Thus, you are adding a `Variant` and not a `Range` object to the collection.

Comment: Many thanks for solution and explanation, removing the parentheses worked!

Answer (score 1):

You use named ranges incorrectly. Compare with the code below, to see where the rror occurs:

```
Sub CollectionTest()
    Dim coll As New Collection
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range

    'Set rng1 = someNamedRange 'gives an error!
    Set rng2 = Range("someNamedRange")

    'here you can see, how to add named ranges to a collection - you have two valid ways, through a variables or directly
    coll.Add someNamedRange
    coll.Add rng2
    coll.Add Range("someNamedRange")

    'MsgBox coll(1).Address 'would give an error: object required
    'both lines below work as expected
    MsgBox coll(2).Address
    MsgBox coll(3).Address
End Sub
```